# jQuery Difference Between .eq(count) and [count]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my further understanding of jQuery, what is the difference between:

```
var allDivs = jQuery('div');
for( var count = allDivs.length - 1; count >= 0; count-- ) {
    var elem = allDivs.eq(count);
    if( elem.css('margin-left') == '-15px' ) {
        elem.css({'margin-left':'0'});
    }
}
```

And:

```
var allDivs = jQuery('div');
for( var count = allDivs.length - 1; count >= 0; count-- ) {
    var elem = allDivs[count];
    if( elem.css('margin-left') == '-15px' ) {
        elem.css({'margin-left':'0'});
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd see by trying them out that the second doesn't work… And the error message would be quite helpful.

Comment: I needed an explanation so I could understand it, and Guffa's was quite helpful, yours was not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`allDivs.eq(count)` will return a jQuery object that contains the element that you specified.

`allDivs[count]` will return the DOM element object that you specified, so you won't be able to use the `css` method on it, as that is a jQuery method.

Using `$(allDivs[count])` gives the same result as `allDivs.eq(count)` (at least as long as `count` specifies an element that exists in `allDivs`).

Comment: How would I be able to use $(allDivs[count]) in my above function?

Comment: @RickHelston: Like this: `var elem = $(allDivs[count]);`